# How to validate an input date from individual day, month, year input in Laravel 5

Tags: php, date, laravel-5

I have a user registration form which takes input birth day split in 3 different input fields i.e. day, month, year

```
{!! Form::selectMonth('month', null) !!}
{!! Form::selectRange('day', 1, 31, null) !!}
{!! Form::selectYear('year', Carbon\Carbon::now()->year, (new Carbon\Carbon('100 years ago'))->year, null) !!}
```

In the backend I have modified the `Registrar.php/validator()` to check the input date is a valid one:

```
public function validator(array $data) {

    $data['date_of_birth'] = Carbon::create($data['year'], $data['month'], $data['day'], 0, 0, 0)->toDateString();
    $current_year          = Carbon::now()->year;
    $hundred_years_ago     = (new Carbon("100 years ago"))->year;

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'year'          => 'Required|Integer|Between:'.$hundred_years_ago.','.$current_year,
        'month'         => 'Required|Integer|Between:1,12',
        'day'           => 'Required|Integer|Between:1,31',
        'date_of_birth' => 'Required|Date',
    ]);

}
```

But surely it doesn't check if an invalid date was provided. If the user provides an invalid date such as `31st February, 1982`, the `Carbon::create()` transforms the date to `3rd March, 1982` which turns out to be a valid one.

If I want to filter this type of date input what do I need to do? I do believe this is likely a very common requirement for those who don't use any datepicker of some sort.

Comment: [checkdate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) function?

Comment: I know the usage of `checkdate()` function. But I cannot quite figure out how to use it with laravel validators. Should I write a custom validator extending the default validator and create a service provider [like this](http://www.sitepoint.com/data-validation-laravel-right-way-custom-validators/) or are their any other more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel using the `strtotime` and `checkdate` functions to [validate a date](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L1311-L1331).

How the `validateDate` function of Laravel works? An example:

```
strtotime('30-2-2015'); // returns a timestamp
checkdate(2, 30, 2015); // returns false
// laravel raises an error
```

Therefore, the value of `$data['date_of_birth']` should be a `string` in a particular format.

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
    $data['date_of_birth'] = $data['day'].'-'.$data['month'].'-'.$data['year'];
    $current_year          = Carbon::now()->year;
    $hundred_years_ago     = (new Carbon("100 years ago"))->year;

    return Validator::make($data, [
        'year'          => 'Required|Integer|Between:'.$hundred_years_ago.','.$current_year,
        'date_of_birth' => 'Required|Date',
    ]);
}
```

Also you can ignore the validation of `day` and `month`, since the date will be validated.

Comment: Not really. It's not about the format. It's about filtering invalid date. Php strtotime also converts `31st February, 1982` to `3rd March, 1982` (Try this: `date("jS F, Y", strtotime("31-2-1982"));`). 

So, in your code 31st February, 1982 will not raise validation error. The point is if a user inputs 31st February, they are just messing with you. So you need to raise a validation error for that particular type of input (which is more logical from user perspective).